# Which $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfy the equation $|z-i|=\sqrt{2}|\bar{z}+1|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $S$ be the set of all complex numbers $z$ satisfying the rule $$|z-i|=\sqrt{2}|\bar{z}+1|$$

Show that $S$ contains points on a circle.

My attempt,

By substituting $z = x + yi$, and squaring both sides. But I can't get the circle form.

Comment: perhaps you like to include the final forms that you have?

Comment: On substitution $z=x+iy$ and squaring as said,
$x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 2((x+1)^2+y^2)$ which is a circle

Comment: But how to eliminate the imaginary number? @samjoe

Comment: @Mathxx if $z=x+iy$ then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. Note that $\overline{z}=x-iy$.

$$\begin{align}
|z-i|&=\sqrt{2}|\overline{z}+1|\\
|z-i|^2&=2|\overline{z}+1|^2\\
|x+i(y-1)|^2&=2|(x+1)-iy|^2\\
x^2+(y-1)^2&=2(x+1)^2+y^2)\\
x^2+4x+2+y^2+2y-1&=0\\
(x+2)^2+(y+1)^2&=2^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Altenative if you are familiar with [Circles of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius),

$$|z-i| = \sqrt{2}|\bar{z}+1|=\sqrt{2}|z+1|=\sqrt{2}|z-(-1)|$$

Here $i$ and $-1$ are the foci.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the complex equation of a circle and complex square completion:

- $|z-a| = r$ is the circle with radius $r$ around $a = a_x + ia_y$
  $$|z-a|^2 = |z|^2 + |a|^2 - 2Re(\bar z a)$$
- Furthermore, note that $|\bar z+1| = |z+1|$
- $|z-i|=\sqrt{2}|\bar{z}+1|$ becomes
  $$|z|^2 + 1 -2Re(\bar z i)=2(|z|^2 + 1 +2Re(\bar z \cdot 1))\Leftrightarrow$$
  $$|z|^2 + 1 + 2Re(\bar z (2+i)) \stackrel{square\; compl.}{=} |z-(-2-i)|^2+1-5 =  |z-(-2-i)|^2-4 = 0 \Leftrightarrow$$
  $$\boxed{|z-(-2-i)|^2 = 4}$$
  This is a circle around $a= -2-i$ with radius $r= 2$.